Why does not selenium takes the attribute from the selected tag but it does in a separate file?
In this code, im trying to get and save links and then open them, once open, i want to press a button that sends me to another page and i want to press a button that sends me to the page i want, the problem is i have to do this 500 times and more, so i automate it but the problem comes now, if i do the code to press the button, it says i could'nt find it, this is not my fault, the css selected is well written, i dont now if if a selenium thing, this is my whole code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
# funcion para iniciar el navegador y configurarlo
def prepare_browser(waiting_time=5):
    # ruta al perfil de usuario de firefox para cargar cookies
    profile_path = "C:\\Users\\donal\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\1om9itxe.default-release"
    # darle opciones al navegador
    options = Options()

    options.add_argument(f"-profile")
    options.add_argument(profile_path)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    # darle la opcion de iniciar en pantalla completa
    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.get("https://nintendoproject.com/vip/catalogo-completo-nintendo-switch/")

    time.sleep(waiting_time)

    return driver


# guardar la devolucion de la funcion
driver = prepare_browser()


# funcion para buscar los links y sacar el nombre de los juegos
# junto con los links y mas informacion de ellos
def get_games_info(driver, waiting_time=5):
    # sacar los links que hay en la pagina
    game_links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div > b > span > a")

    # bucle para recorrer todos los links y hacerlos textos
    with open("first_links.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        # ir al inicio del archivo
        file.seek(0)

        # leer todas las lineas del archivo y guardarlas en una variable
        existing_links = file.readlines()

        # abrir un nuevo archivo para escribir los nuevos enlaces
        with open("second_links.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as second_file:
            # ir al incio del archivo
            second_file.seek(0)

            # leer los links de este archivo
            second_file_read_links = [second_file_read_link.strip() for second_file_read_link in second_file.readlines()]

            # iterar sobre los enlaces para abrirlos
            for link in existing_links:
                link = link.strip()

                driver.get(link)

                # clase del boton para ir a la siguientep pagina
                next_page_button_location = ".elementor-button.elementor-button-link.elementor-size-sm.elementor-animation-float"

                # esperar {waiting_time} para que cargue la pagina
                time.sleep(waiting_time)

                # ubicar el boton y darle click
                next_page_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, next_page_button_location)
                next_page_button.click()

                # esperar {waiting_time} para que cargue la pagina
                time.sleep(waiting_time)

                # localizar las etiquetas a dentro de span para sacarles el enlace
                game_download_links = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")

                # esperar {waiting_time} para que cargue la pagina
                time.sleep(waiting_time)

                # sacar el atributo
                game_download_link_attributes = game_download_links.get_attribute("href")
                print(game_download_link_attributes)

                if game_download_link_attributes not in second_file_read_links:
                    second_file.write(game_download_link_attributes)


get_games_info(driver)

driver.quit()

the thing is that in a separate file it works, this is the other code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time

profile_path = "C:\\Users\\donal\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\1om9itxe.default-release"
# darle opciones al navegador
options = Options()

options.add_argument(f"-profile")
options.add_argument(profile_path)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://nintendoproject.com/13-xiii-remake-rom-xci-nsenlaces-vip/")

time.sleep(5)

button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wp-block-button__link.wp-element-button")
attr = button.get_attribute("href")
print(attr)
button.click()
time.sleep(5)

current_url = driver.current_url
print(current_url)


driver.quit()

i dont know why it works in this separate file, i tried 3 things, the first one was to take the new url with driver.current_url but it takes the previous one, not the new one, the second was to take the button href that sends me to the page i want to go, and last one open the link by pressing the button, but none of them work in the main file, just in this file, why!!!? i spent 4 hours on this
